# Will and would modal verb differences

Tags: modal-verbs, will-would

> 1). A majority of voters approved changes to Russia's constitution that **would** allow president valdmir putin to hold power until 2036

> 2). A majority of voters approved changes to Russia's constitution that **will** allow president valdmir putin to hold power until 2036

Which of the following sentences is correct?? If both are correct, What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences???

I know as the sentence is in past tense we should use "would". But as the constitution is still allowing and will allow for some time in future , can't we use "will"???

Answer (score 1):

The following are correct:

1. Voters are considering changes to Russia’s constitution that would allow President Vladimir Putin to hold power until 2036.
2. A majority of voters approved changes to Russia’s constitution that will allow President Vladimir Putin to hold power until 2036.

“A majority of voters approved changes that would” is wrong, because the the changes are no longer contingent.  The “election” has been held; the changes *will* cause the indicated consequence.

(Not the correction to the spelling and capitalization of the names.)

Comment: Why did you change the text of the first sentence from, *"A majority of voters approved changes..." to "Voters are considering changes..."?

Comment: @gotube — that is the entire point!  While the voters are still considering approving the changes, the consequences are still conditional.  _If_ the voters approve the changes, _then_ they take effect; otherwise, perhaps not.  Everything is [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English).

Comment: Ah. I read it to mean there's still some contingency, even though the voters have approved it. If there's no contingency, then you're right.

Comment: @gotube — “ Impossible to see, the future is.”  Anything might be contingent, if it has not happened yet.  Unless the sentence is about _contingency_ (and typically counter-factuality), use the future tense.

Comment: I don't know the legal workings of Russian referenda, so I'm allowing for the possibility that there are still legal contingencies after the public approves the changes. I don't mean "contingent" in the trivial sense that "anything is possible".

Answer (score 0):

The second one is appropriate, because assuming from the context, the "changes" haven't been made yet. So if they are made, they will be made in the future, so 'will' is appropriate. We hardly ever use 'would' instead of 'will' when the future of both 'now' and the past is the same.